# How To Test route.navigate on Backbone View

Tags: backbone.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm currently developing a Backbone.js application which uses the Mocha, Chai, and Sinon libraries for testing. I'm struggling to code the following test: When a user clicks a button it should redirect the user to home.

Here's how the view looks like:

```
events: {
    'click #navigate-home': 'goHome'
},

initialize: function(options) {
    this.router = options.router;
},

goHome: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.router.navigate('home', { trigger: true });
}
```

And here's the test:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  this.router = new Backbone.Router();
  this.myView = new MyView({
    router: this.router
  });
  this.myView.render();
});

afterEach(function() {
  this.router = null;
  this.myView = null;
});

it('redirects to home', sinon.test(function() {
  var spy = sinon.spy();
  this.router.on({
    'home': spy
  });
  this.myView.$el.find('#navigate-home').trigger('click');
  expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
}));
```

The code works as expected on the browser, but I can't get the test to pass. I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: make sure your View rendered html has been attached to some page elem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my limited experience with Backbone and Unit Testing, I consider this kind of test as an invalid test case.

What you are trying to test in not actually your code but you are trying to add a test case for Backbone library. Similar test cases should actually be part of your Automation (Read about [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)).

I think the correct way to write a Unit Test in your case would be:

```
it('should redirect to home', sinon.test(function() {
  var spy = sinon.spy();
  this.router.on({
    'home': spy
  });

  // This is the difference
  this.myView.goHome({preventDefault: function() { } });

  expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
});
```

Comment: You are completely right. I'm trying to perform to different tests at the same time. What I should do instead, is to have one test to check if the function listens correctly to the 'click' event, and then another test to check whether the function properly triggers the 'home' route on the router. Thanks!